# BubbleSort Output Graph Trouble

Tags: java, execution, bubble-sort

Hi I have written a bubble sort application in JAVA. The application is working fully and give sufficient output, but it doesn't give me an out put for average time.

Here is my code:

```
public class BubbleSort {
static double bestTime = 10000000, worstTime = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int BubArray[] = new int[]{**#interger values are placed in here#**};
         System.out.println("Unsorted List Before Bubble Sort");
         for(int a = 0; a < BubArray.length; a++){
         System.out.print(BubArray[a] + " ");
            }

        System.out.println("\n Bubble Sort Execution ...");

                    for(int i=0; i<10000;i++) {
                        bubbleSortTimeTaken(BubArray, i);
                        }

         int itrs = bubbleSort(BubArray);
    System.out.println("");               
    System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
    System.out.println("Moves Taken for Sort : " + itrs + " Moves.");
    System.out.println("BestTime: " + bestTime + " WorstTime: " + worstTime);
    System.out.print("Sorted Array: \n");

        for(int a = 0; a < BubArray.length; a++){
                System.out.print(BubArray[a] + " ");
        }
}

private static int bubbleSort(int[] BubArray) {

int z = BubArray.length;
int temp = 0;

int itrs = 0;

for(int a = 0; a < z; a++){
        for(int x=1; x < (z-a); x++){

                if(BubArray[x-1] > BubArray[x]){

                        temp = BubArray[x-1];
                        BubArray[x-1] = BubArray[x];
                        BubArray[x] = temp;


                }    

                itrs++;
        }
}

return itrs;
}

public static void bubbleSortTimeTaken(int[] BubArray, int n) 
{
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    bubbleSort(BubArray);   
    double timeTaken = (System.nanoTime() - startTime);
    if (timeTaken > 0)
    {
        worstTime = timeTaken;
    }
    else if (timeTaken < bestTime)
    {
        bestTime = timeTaken;
    }

    System.out.println(n + "," + timeTaken);

}
}
```

But I am unsure of how to a) get the average time for each and also how I would plot the Best, Average and Worst Case results on a graph.

Here is a sample output:

```
Unsorted List Before Bubble Sort
#Integers Values of Unsorted List#

Bubble Sort Execution ... **#(execution number, time in nanoseconds)#**
0,6336584.0
1,5063668.0
2,3364580.0
3,3373289.0
4,3755912.0
5,3383866.0
....
9995,3431772.0
9996,3368312.0
9997,3743469.0
9998,4639362.0
9999,3433638.0

Moves Taken for Sort : 499500 Moves.
BestTime: 1.0E7 WorstTime: 3433638.0
```

Also I'm not sure if my `bubbleSortTimeTaken()` function works properly as 1.0E7 is given for every run of the program regardless of the number of integers used
(100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000) have been tested. I wish to find the average, best and worst case to plot.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if (timeTaken > 0)   // <- PROBLEM, Shouldn't be zero
    {
        worstTime = timeTaken;
    }
    else if (timeTaken < bestTime) //<- PROBLEM! , the 2 comparisons are unrelated
    {
        bestTime = timeTaken;
    }
```

Right there. If `timeTaken`>0, which it will be mostly, the `else if` is never executed.
Thus, `bestTime` never gets updated, and retains the original value (1E7).

To fix this, the function should be modified to look like :

```
public static void bubbleSortTimeTaken(int[] BubArray, int n) 
{
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    bubbleSort(BubArray);   
    double timeTaken = (System.nanoTime() - startTime);
    if (timeTaken > worstTime)
    {
        worstTime = timeTaken;
    }
    if (timeTaken < bestTime)
    {
        bestTime = timeTaken;
    }

    System.out.println(n + "," + timeTaken);

}
}
```

Note that  I have added a possible fix about `worstTime` too.

Comment: fixed it thank you. It's now outputting the correct (what I'd expect) results. You have helped me out a lot. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (timeTaken > 0)
{
    worstTime = timeTaken;
}
```

This should be

```
 if (timeTaken > worstTime)
{
    worstTime = timeTaken;
}
```

otherwise you'll not be setting this properly. This explains why your bestTime is always 10e7.

To find the average, simply do it a certain number of times, recording all the times, then add them and divide by number of times done.

Comment: Thank you for your input, the part about average has helped me out a lot!